# Build JAR file with IntelliJ 14: Unable to access jarfile?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm trying to generate a JAR file out of a small library I'm writing. I understand that I need to add a ***custom Run/Debug Configuration*** to achieve that. So, I added this new *JAR Application* configuration:

[image: Build Jar Configuration]

---

When I run the module with this configuration, I get this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1256 -jar ""
Error: Unable to access jarfile 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not sure why, but I think it has something to do with the warning in the bottom of the screenshot, which I can't figure out why I have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more and more research, It seams that **Artifacts** are the way to build JAR files in intelliJ IDEA.

- File | Project Structure | Artifacts.
- New Artifact -> JAR -> From modules with dependencies
- Select the lib module, then click Ok
- And when you want to generate the JAR: **Build | Build artifacts | "artifact name"**

[Source](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/)