# How do i fix "Unable to access Jar file" in IntelliJ idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So, I made a simple HelloWorld program and followed the IntelliJ idea tips and instructions on how to create my first program, although I still have a problem which is after I made an artifact of the program and set it at the "Edit Configurations" tab, it says this error.

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\nazgi\IdeaProjects\HelloWorld\artifacts\HelloWorld_jar
```

And before you ask I did change the directory, the original directory was 
`C:/Users/nazgi/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld`

Comment: Is it possible that you got confused with the directions of `/` which usually found in Linux and ``\`` which usually found in Windows?

Comment: no no, that was a mistake in this question, but i used \ in the directory folder, i changed the directory multiple times now, and i got into the folder in my laptop but not my pc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build JAR file with IntelliJ 14: Unable to access jarfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291638/build-jar-file-with-intellij-14-unable-to-access-jarfile)

Answer (score 2):

Okay so i figured it out, my directory was not specific enough so the program couldnt find the JAR file, so i changes the directory to

```
....\Java\HelloWorld\out\artifacts...\HelloWorld.jar
```